# How to remove element of List according to a parameter in Android

Tags: java, android, calendar, iterator

I have this part of Android code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    c.setTime(iterator.next().loadData());
    if(XXX){
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Each item whose date is between January and September remains in the list, then in September all items older will be removed.
At the turn of year I would like a repeat everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Calendar` [after](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#after(java.lang.Object)) and [before](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#before(java.lang.Object)) methods.

On the other way you can just **compare** the month and the year using [get](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) method. For example:

```
c.get(Calendar.MONTH) // it would return the month of your date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){

c.setTime(iterator.next().loadData());
if(XXX){
    iterator.remove();
    notifyDataHasChanged();
}
```

You should use `notifyDataHasChanged`method in your Adapter class when you re